# Error: Unable to replace text string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL 9.5 database, I have a table called `my_table` containing three columns `id` `character varying (254)`, `val_1 numeric` and `val_2 numeric`. The following query:

```
Select id, val_1, val_2 from my_table limit 4;
```

returns four sample rows:

```
id         val_1   val_2
1147_1     72      61
1228_1     73      67
1255_1     74      68
1337_1     79      66
```

I wanted to change the data type of `id` column thus I tried:

```
Alter table my_table alter column id type integer using id::integer;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1147_1"
```

To get rid of these `""`, I tried:

```
Update my_table set id = replace(id, '"','');
```

The query returned successfully. But, when I tried to change the data type I again get the same error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1147_1"`. Can someone help me to fix this problem? I am unable to figure out that why I keep getting the same error even I successfully executed `replace()` command.

Comment: `1147_1` **is not** a valid integer. How do you want to convert it? Should it be `1147` or `11471`?

Comment: In that case, I think I can extract the number using substring() command. I wanted to change the data type for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `id` values to be a valid integers, e.g. remove underscores:

```
alter table my_table alter column id type integer using replace(id, '_', '')::integer;
```